# asp.net mvc site search using web crawler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a search for my asp mvc website. I've checked out Lucene.net but it searches a database for text and as far as I can tell it does not crawl a site to get the URL's. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this? I've been searching the net for some examples but am having a hard time finding what i need. I've used sphider for php sites but can't find anything comparable for asp mvc.

Comment: here's an [article](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-httpwebrequest-using-asp-net-mvc3/) incase u want to write a simple crawler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple but effective if you don't want to invest in creating your own search:
http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gss.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also try our product ['SearchUnit'](https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/index.html), there's a free community edition and a paid edition.  There's an MVC specific getting started guide here https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/tutorials/setup-MVC-search-engine/